ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : not able to convert string into JSON object
I get it the json string from third party API call using below C# method in my API. Now I need to return this via my API.
using var responseStream =  response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

JSON data received:
{
   "resources":[
      {
         "asset_id":"0be6920b67900d9dcb692dafc8752144",
         "public_id":"312555/Deep_Sleep_iv1xdf",
         "format":"png",
         "version":1735387533,
         "resource_type":"image",
         "type":"upload",
         "created_at":"2024-12-28T12:05:33Z",
         "bytes":58989,
         "width":612,
         "height":412,
         "asset_folder":"312555",
         "display_name":"Deep Sleep",
         "url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387533/312555/Deep_Sleep_iv1xdf.png",
         "secure_url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387533/312555/Deep_Sleep_iv1xdf.png"
      },
      {
         "asset_id":"8726add67eb8a3b7462a078f335acddc",
         "public_id":"312555/stage3negotiation_e5g3z9",
         "format":"jpg",
         "version":1735387420,
         "resource_type":"image",
         "type":"upload",
         "created_at":"2024-12-28T12:03:40Z",
         "bytes":1410672,
         "width":2000,
         "height":1333,
         "asset_folder":"312555",
         "display_name":"stage3negotiation",
         "url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387420/312555/stage3negotiation_e5g3z9.jpg",
         "secure_url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387420/312555/stage3negotiation_e5g3z9.jpg"
      },
      {
         "asset_id":"5255df4456604743b34769c8105f1552",
         "public_id":"312555/TROPICAT-Photo-14-11-2024-1-04-31-pm_kndjym",
         "format":"jpg",
         "version":1735387420,
         "resource_type":"image",
         "type":"upload",
         "created_at":"2024-12-28T12:03:40Z",
         "bytes":131855,
         "width":600,
         "height":800,
         "asset_folder":"312555",
         "display_name":"TROPICAT-Photo-14-11-2024-1-04-31-pm",
         "url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387420/312555/TROPICAT-Photo-14-11-2024-1-04-31-pm_kndjym.jpg",
         "secure_url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387420/312555/TROPICAT-Photo-14-11-2024-1-04-31-pm_kndjym.jpg"
      },
      {
         "asset_id":"c62a24332bd62b595672f5086772751e",
         "public_id":"312555/stage4undercontract_iwglqm",
         "format":"webp",
         "version":1735387420,
         "resource_type":"image",
         "type":"upload",
         "created_at":"2024-12-28T12:03:40Z",
         "bytes":99008,
         "width":1600,
         "height":1060,
         "asset_folder":"312555",
         "display_name":"stage4undercontract",
         "url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387420/312555/stage4undercontract_iwglqm.webp",
         "secure_url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/catco-mls/image/upload/v1735387420/312555/stage4undercontract_iwglqm.webp"
      }
   ],
   "total_count":4,
   "next_cursor":null
}

.NET class to hold that information:
public class Cloudinary
{
    public class Resource
    {
        public string asset_id { get; set; }
        public string public_id { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public int version { get; set; }
        public string resource_type { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public int bytes { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public string asset_folder { get; set; }
        public string display_name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string secure_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
        public int total_count { get; set; }
        public object next_cursor { get; set; }
    }
}

I have tried multiple options, here are few.
Option 1
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

var data =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Cloudinary.Root>(result);

I get this error when trying this code:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.LibraryAdmin.Models.Cloudinary+Root]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)

Option 2
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using var responseStream =  response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

    Cloudinary.Resource? resource = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Cloudinary.Resource>(responseStream);

    return resource;
}

I get no error when using this code, but it does produce the desired result, all the fields are null when it returns from the API.
My actual method is:
public async static Task<List<Cloudinary.Resource>> GetImages(string BoatId)

Please advise, what am I doing wrong?

The error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.LibraryAdmin.Models.Cloudinary+Root] mentioned that you are deserializing to List<Cloudinary.Root>, but from your code, you are deserializing to Cloudinary.Root: JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Cloudinary.Root>(result). Are you sure you are providing the correct code?

Your Option 1 code works fine. Demo
